# What's the easiest way to get the current location of an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-location

I already know how to use the CLLocationManager, so I could do it the hard way, with delegates and all that.

But I'd like to have a convenience method that just gets the current location, once, and blocks until it gets the result.

Comment: You should clarify the question: If you know how to use CLLocationManager - what's the problem implementing such a "convenience method"?

Comment: I think the problem is it's not that easy. Normally it returns an old location first, followed by a wildly innacurate one, followed by progressively better ones, at what point do you decide you have the one you want? It's really up to you.

Answer (score 44):

What I do is implement a singleton class to manage updates from core location.  To access my current location, I do a `CLLocation *myLocation = [[LocationManager sharedInstance] currentLocation];`  If you wanted to block the main thread you could do something like this:

```
while ([[LocationManager sharedInstance] locationKnown] == NO){
   //blocking here
   //do stuff here, dont forget to have some kind of timeout to get out of this blocked    //state
}
```

However, as it has been already pointed out, blocking the main thread is probably not a good idea, but this can be a good jumping off point as you are building something.  You will also notice that the class I wrote checks the timestamp on location updates and ignores any that are old, to prevent the problem of getting stale data from core location.

This is the singleton class I wrote.  Please note that it is a little rough around the edges:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface  LocationController : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
}

+ (LocationController *)sharedInstance;

-(void) start;
-(void) stop;
-(BOOL) locationKnown;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *currentLocation;

@end
@implementation LocationController

@synthesize currentLocation;

static LocationController *sharedInstance;

+ (LocationController *)sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!sharedInstance)
            sharedInstance=[[LocationController alloc] init];       
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

+(id)alloc {
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSAssert(sharedInstance == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton LocationController.");
        sharedInstance = [super alloc];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        [self start];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) start {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void) stop {
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

-(BOOL) locationKnown { 
     if (round(currentLocation.speed) == -1) return NO; else return YES; 
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    //if the time interval returned from core location is more than two minutes we ignore it because it might be from an old session
    if ( abs([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate: [NSDate date]]) < 120) {     
        self.currentLocation = newLocation;
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert;
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [locationManager release];
    [currentLocation release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It is a nice little controller to have available. One thing i found though was that the locationKnown method wasn't very accurate - it always returned YES because currentLocation is initialised in the init method. Here is an alternative version of the method that uses the speed property to determine whether the user's location has been received:

-(BOOL) locationKnown {
    if (round(currentLocation.speed) == -1) 
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}

Comment: You have only allocated the resources but have not released it. Can you please tell me where would you release it that it wont cause any issue.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such convenience and you shouldn't create your own.  "Blocks until it gets the result" is **extremely bad** programming practice on a device like the iPhone.  It can take seconds to retrieve a location; you should never make your users wait like that, and delegates ensure they don't.

Comment: Threads, yes, when combined with a callback on completion.  Where the callback is scheduled on the originating run loop.  Which gets you an interface exactly like the CLLocationManager's delegate already has.  "Block until done" is never a good design in end-user apps.

Comment: I disagree, "blocks until done" has many legitimate uses in all kinds of apps, and is not synonymous with "freezes the UI until done".  Trying to make *everything* asynchronous just leads to bizarre behavior and buggy apps.  Who cares how quick the UI appears/responds if the information it needs to display isn't available yet?  Async operations have their place, and so do blocking ones.  It's not a case where one is good and the other is bad.

Comment: “Who cares how quick the UI appears/responds”? The user does. A frozen UI is frustrating, and should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: Async code is even harder to debug because it loses clarity.
 
Polling loops, used improperly, lead to 100% CPU load and will kill the battery. sleep() leads UI delays. Notifications and/or delegates are the way to go (although callbacks are fugly... blocks ftw).  Engineering is all about tradeoffs, laziness and satisfying the user.

Answer (score 4):

There are no "convenience methods" unless you code them yourself, but you'd still need to implement the delegate methods in whatever custom code you use to make things "convenient."

The delegate pattern is there for a reason, and as delegates are a big part of Objective-C, I recommend you get comfortable with them.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciated the answer by Brad Smith. Implementing it I discovered that one of the methods he employs is deprecated as of iOS6. To write code that will work with both iOS5 and iOS6, use the following:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    if (abs([[locations lastObject] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]) < 120) {
        [self setCurrentLocation:[locations lastObject]];
    }
}

// Backward compatibility with iOS5.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:oldLocation, newLocation, nil];
    [self locationManager:manager didUpdateLocations:locations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified and combined multiple answers to where the location is only updated if it's valid.

It also works under OSX as well as iOS.

This assumes the use-case where the current location is suddenly desired by the user.  If it takes more than 100 ms in this example, it's considered an error.  (Assumes the GPS IC &| Wifi (Apple's Skyhook clone) is already fired up and has a good fix already.)

```
#import "LocationManager.h"

// wait up to 100 ms
CLLocation *location = [LocationManager currentLocationByWaitingUpToMilliseconds:100];
if (!location) {
    NSLog(@"no location :(");
    return; 
}
// location is good, yay
```

https://gist.github.com/6972228