# Load MKMapView with current location

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

For the life of me I can't get something that seems like it should be simple to work. I have a navigation controller and am trying to push an MKMapView onto the stack that loads the user's current location. The problem is that the user's location seems to be only available after the MKMapView is pushed onto the navigation controller, thus loading the view. That being the case, I can't provide the proper longitude and latitude for the userLocation object until after it is loaded. So what's happening is it's getting loaded with coordinates 0,0 and showing nothing. The second time it loads is fine. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your predicament I would query the device's location before I pushed the mapView onto the navigation controller. Then simply pass this location to the mapView's controller and tell it to center to it, say in its viewWillAppear method.

Have a look at the code in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459355/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-location-of-an-iphone). I'd use this class to get the current location and pass it to the map.