# Updating/Zooming Into Current Location on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

Ok so I am trying to get the same zoom in/location update feature that the iPhone Maps application has when you tap on the current location button. I am using code I found from [here](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459355/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-location-of-an-iphone)(code from the post by Brad Smith) to do most of the work. So all I really need to do is center the map around the updated current location and zoom in a little further every time there is an update.

Right now I am having some difficulty testing for whether centerCoord is null or not. As you can see from the results(listed below) it crashes for some reason which I can't figure out. Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void) showCurrentLocationButtonTapped {
    NSLog(@"Showing current location.");

    locController = [[LocationController alloc] init];

    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    zoomTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(zoomToCurrentLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void) zoomToCurrentLocation {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = self.locController.currentLocation.coordinate;
    NSLog(@"Checking if loc controller is null");
    if (!self.locController) {
        NSLog(@"centerCoord is null!");
    }
    NSLog(@"centerCoord: %@",centerCoord);
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:centerCoord zoomLevel:7 animated:YES];
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
2010-11-10 14:56:11.002 App Name[5278:207] Showing current location.
2010-11-10 14:56:11.504 App Name[5278:207] Checking if loc controller is null
2010-11-10 14:56:11.505 App Name[5278:207] centerCoord: (null)
2010-11-10 14:56:12.004 App Name[5278:207] Checking if loc controller is null
2010-11-10 14:56:12.004 App Name[5278:207] centerCoord: (null)
2010-11-10 14:56:12.504 App Name[5278:207] Checking if loc controller is null
```

I am aware I am not testing for the null-ness of centerCoord, but if I do this:

```
if (!centerCoord) {
```

I get an error on that line saying:

```
MapViewController.m:55: error: wrong type argument to unary exclamation mark
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need to do:

First, check if location services is enabled:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    [self findUserLocation];
```

Then in your findUserLocation method, instantiate your CLLocationManager and start receiving updates:

```
- (void)findUserLocation
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager_ = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracy{ChooseYourOptionHere};
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

And finally, implement this delegate method, which will get called every time an update is received. Check the current location's accuracy against your desired accuracy (set above), center the map if you are happy with it AND don't forget to stop the location manager from receiving updates:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if ([newLocation horizontalAccuracy] < [manager desiredAccuracy])
    {
        // Accuracy is good enough, zoom to current location
        [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
// else keep trying...
}
```

Comment: And I just realised this is like 6 months old, not sure why it was bumped to the top again?

Comment: I have no idea, heh. Thanks for the answer though, I will go back to that portion of my project and do what you suggested and if it helps me do what I am looking for I'll be sure to accept your answer. :) You got +1 from me for answering this in anycase.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Location Controller is taking time to update your location.
Try to set your timer to 30 seconds and see what happens.

Comment: I did 5 seconds instead of 30, as 30 is too long. The little blue dot shows up on a zoomed-out map. And after 5 seconds, it crashes. Here is the console output: 2010-11-10 17:24:09.507 App Name[5731:207] Showing current location.
Wed Nov 10 17:24:10 ...: CGImageCreateWithImageProvider: invalid image size: 0 x 0.
2010-11-10 17:24:14.509 App Name[5731:207] Checking if loc controller is null

Comment: MapViewController.m:55: error: wrong type argument to unary exclamation mark means that you can't use the exclamation mark for this. Try CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(centerCoord).