# Get User's Country

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, localization

I just wanted to know how I could find out the current user's country using Xcode (iPhone Dev SDK).

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459355/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-location-of-an-iphone

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to get the users country you can do two things. The easiest is to deciper it from their localization settings.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *country = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[locale localeIdentifier]];
```

This can be unreliable (e.g. a user who is abroad). If you depend on the information you should use CoreLocation to find the users current location and then use reverse geo-tagging to get the country from the co-ordinates. Take a look at the [CoreLocation Framework reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html). It should help you.

Comment: When I run this code I get "English (United Kingdom)". For my app I am using an API and need to see if the user is US based (It doesn't matter if they are currently abroad). Is the string returned for USA users "English (United States)". I can't find it anywhere and have to be 100% sure!

Comment: It should be. I believe this just gets their language settings so if you take a look through the language options in your iPhone's settings you will be able to see the various options. The only problem will be someone who lives in the US and speaks a foreign language. It might be best for you to use Core Location.

Comment: Alright cheers! I will consider using Core Location in the future. The API I am using is all English so it should be ok for now!

Comment: NSLocale getting Country  but, even if we moved to other country it won't get , it reading from phone region.