# Current location alert access

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location

What is the class or API used to popup the alert to the user for their current location access permission to the app?

Answer (score 3):

When you are using core-location the app shows automatically the alert for permission. You can't disable/enable that by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're asking ... is this related to a web application? iphone?  android?  java?  fortran?  Anyway, i'll go on a limb here and think you're referring to the HTML5 GeoLocation API:

- http://html5demos.com/geo

This other question may be of value to you if it's iOS and you don't want to do it once with HTML5 ...

[What's the easiest way to get the current location of an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459355/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-location-of-an-iphone)