# URL with Current Location to Google Maps from iPad fails

Tags: url, google-maps

I am trying to create a URL that takes a user from where they are currently to any destination and provides directions.  The URL below works fine in iOS on the iPhone, but does not on the iPad as it prompts be to clarify what Current Location is:

[http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=350 Broadway,%20New%20York,%20New%20York](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=350%20Broadway,%20New%20York,%20New%20York)

How can I make this work in both the iPhone and the iPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I've Research this but...

I have researched about this for a while, and I believe there is no way to specify `Current Location`. I know passing `Current Location` as a parameter on iPhone works, but it is recognized as **string** Current Location rather than what you are intended.

### Alternative Way

The alternative way is to get the coordinate of the user using `Core Location`, and then pass this coordinate as `saddr` parameter.

It may be a bit ugly on Maps app because there will be an annotation that indicates the user's current location and another pin annotation that indicates the coordinate you passed.

### How to Get the Current User Location

Here's a post for getting the user location.
[What's the easiest way to get the current location of an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459355/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-location-of-an-iphone)

Comment: This was going to be my plan B approach.  Hopefully Apple gets these mapping apps to work consistently.

Comment: Yeah I also expect you to know Plan B, but there is not much resource about explaining the inconsistency between iPhone and iPad. I hope there's solution or at least hack for this :(

Answer (score 2):

It's actually very simple, the Google Maps API documentation says to simply leave `saddr` blank and that will cause it to use "Current Location" as the starting point for your Directions request.

Like this:

> comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA+94043