# mapping current location to destination location in googleMaps

Tags: iphone, ios4, google-maps, nsurl

I have a button on my annotation that calls google maps as follows.
I'm trying to map a route from my known current location to the destination location passed from the annotation record.

The current location fails to be recognized in google maps and instead suggests a random place like Current, Dent, Missouri.

```
- (IBAction)GoogleMap
{
  NSString *mapAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@",location.address, location.city, location.state, location.zipcode];

  NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%@",  
                 // 40.7406578, -74.0020894, test coordinates
                 [mapAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

}

any idea where I am going wrong here? should this not work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, typing "Current Location" into Google Maps does not actually send you to your current location.

I would suggest getting your current location using [the method from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459355/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-the-current-location-of-an-iphone) and then passing the coordinates from the `CLLocation` object to Google Maps instead.